# mongod users can not create a password？

Tags: mongodb

How can I fix the situation where I can not add a password?

```
db.createUser({user:'root',pwd:'hello!0.', roles:[{role:'userAdminAnyDatabase', db:'admin'}]})  

Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "root",
    "roles" : [
            {
              "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
              "db" : "admin"
            }
    ]
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb defaults without permission access so you need to open access access auth = ture